# Making a layout in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I just begin to work on making a layout with Grid. I tried to make it using the HBoxlayout and VBoxlayout. But How to set the position of the layout. I searched out and I found the setAlignment option but it isn't working on it.
So how to do its postioning of layouts like the image?

this is the layout I want to make

[image][check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtj4e.jpg)

```
#include "mainscreen.h"
#include "ui_mainscreen.h"
#include<QLayout>
#include<QPushButton>

MainScreen::MainScreen(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGridLayout *layout=new QGridLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout=new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton *x=new QPushButton;
    hlayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    hlayout->addWidget(x);
    layout->addChildLayout(hlayout);


this->setLayout(layout);
    this->show();
}

MainScreen::~MainScreen()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: What proportion are there between the elements and what elements are they? It also shows what you have tried

Comment: I have added the image of complete UI I want to make.

Comment: That image is not descriptive, please try hard and show a better image, for example use paint, also show the code you have tried. SO is not a software writing service

Comment: I have tried to put a HBoxlayout  on the top. and then i am going to add some labels in it. But it is not working. The idea is to create a grid, then a hbox on the top and bottom and a vbox on left and a grid in left of the space.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the difference b/w an item and a widget. Like i've seen two different kind of functions addWidget() and addItem(). I know widget but I couldn't understand what item is referring to? I already searched on web but found nothing about it.

Comment: an item is a container element, this item can have a widget or a layout as content, usually do not use addItem(), it should be enough with addLayout() and addWidget().

Answer (score 0):

You can find good information about Layout in this Tutorial from Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html

Two things that are important for your Layout:

1. You need to nest several layout. Themain layout will be a VBoxlayout that contains the top and bottom Widget and one HBoxLayout in the middle. The HBoxLayout contain the other two widgets.
2. Two get different size for the two middle widgtes you need to give either a Stretch factor to the Layout or define sizes for the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider doing the following

```
    QHBoxLayout *TopLayout    = new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *BottomLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *MiddleLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton *topBtn         = new QPushButton;
    QPushButton *bottomBtn      = new QPushButton;
    QPushButton *LeftMiddleBtn  = new QPushButton;
    QPushButton *RightMiddleBtn = new QPushButton;

    TopLayout->addWidget(topBtn);
    BottomLayout->addWidget(bottomBtn);
    // order matters here (i.e. the first addWidget will be placed in the left)
    MiddleLayout->addWidget(LeftMiddleBtn);
    MiddleLayout->addWidget(RightMiddleBtn);

    // order matters here
    mainLayout->addLayout(TopLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(MiddleLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(BottomLayout);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
```

More convenient and right approach is to use Qt Designer or Qt Creator for this matter.

Comment: "right approach", not any more (or less) right than coding the layout by hand.

Answer (score 0):

`QMainWindow` is a spatial case. It already has a layout set and it is impossible to change layout in widget! Reason is that `QMainWindow` has lots of other functionalities like menu, docking, status bar.

So how to make it work?

You have to [set central widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget):

```
MainScreen::MainScreen(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto widget = new QWidget();
    setCentalWidget(widget);

    auto vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    // add your stuff here
    // some example for testing:
    vLayout->addWidget(new QButton("Test button"));
    vLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Nice label"));
    vLayout->addWidget(new QTextEdit);
}
```

Also you are doing something wrong since this line `ui->setupUi(this);` indicates that you are using Qt Designer (design ui by mouse) and this means that layout should not be setup directly by code!

Comment: setCentralWidget isn't working. Do i need to make any object for it?

Comment: I'm sure it does work. Simple `QWidget` will handle this nicely if you add other widgets to layout owned by central widget. Update question if it don't work.

Comment: @MarekR MainScreen is not a QMainWindow, is a QWidget